# SDL2 Audio Callback restricted to 8bit?

Tags: c, audio, sdl, sdl-2

Having read through the SDL2 audio documentation (which is kind of woeful), I can see that there are various audio formats available - including unsigned & signed 8bit, 16bit, 32bitfloat. So far so good. 
I'm stuck using SDL for this project, and I'd like to do some simple audio synthesis in 16bit. So I've set the format in my SDL_AudioSpec struct to AUDIO_U16SYS as per this page
https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AudioSpec

However, when I look at the callback documentation on the same page (and in fact everywhere else I've looked on the web), the audio buffer in the callback is *Uint8:

```
void SDL_AudioCallback(void*  userdata,
                       Uint8* stream,
                       int    len)
```

That being the case I can't see how I'd actually pass 16bit audio to SDL. It looks like it is always going to receive audio as 8bit, and the library just upsamples to the desired bitrate. But that sounds crazy. Is that correct, or am I missing something. For example, is there (somehow) an alternative callback prototype corresponding to eg. AUDIO_U16SYS, or do I have to use other methods for higher bitrates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `stream` is indeed a pointer to an 8-bit integer, you can cast it to the correct type. It's just a generic pointer to a stream of bytes, how those bytes should be interpreted (like for example combining every two bytes to a 16-bit word) is up to you.

So in the callback function, just do e.g.

```
Uint16 *stream16 = (Uint16 *) stream;
```

Comment: Ah, great. Thanks for the quick answer.
Fairly obvious when you point it out but my brain was being slow.

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem the whole story - and again, nothing in the docs that i can find covers it. If I switch to AUDIO_U16SYS, change my audio ranges from (0-255) to (0-65535) and use your cast pointer method above, I get distorted audio. Probably I need to post more code, and perhaps best to start a new question at this point. Thanks for your help anyway - it does answer my original question. I'm just even more confused than I thought :)

Comment: Ah! ok so I missed that the len parameter is the length *in bytes* of the buffer. So as well as changing the format, changing the audio range and casting the stream to 16 bit ints, I also need to divide the length of the buffer by sizeof(Uint16)/sizeof(Uint8). (and the fact that len is measured in bytes was covered in the docs - I just missed it)